# XenServer - Storage XenMotion between 2 servers using direct LAN connection

Tags: xenserver, hetzner

I have two physical servers (recent, Haswell based machines) on which I have installed XenServer 6.5 . Both servers have two NICs. These servers are hosted at the [Hetzner](http://hetzner.de) datacenter.

I have connected a LAN crossover cable between the two servers on one of the NICs.

The other NIC on both servers are facing the Internet directly, with a public IP assigned. I connect to the servers (SSH or XenCenter) using this public IP.

[image: servers architecture]

Both servers have only local storage. No shared storage.

From both servers, I am able to ping the public IP and the private IP of the other server. No problems there. The `xenbr0` has the public IP and the `xenbr1` has the private IP on both servers.

I want to put both servers in the same pool and be able to migrate the VMs between them (Storage XenMotion). But when I try to drag a VM from one server to another, the subsequent dialog box does not allow me to select that server. The reason it gives: `No route to host`.

I have installed the separate NIC precisely for the purpose of having a dedicated internal network for VM migrations.

What do I need to do to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Storage XenMotion makes use of the Management Interface (in your case it should be the xenbr0 - bridge or you call it virtual switch), if the 2 management interfaces cannot communicate with each other, Storage XenMotion will fail.

You need to create a separate Storage Network (using IP in your private network `192.168.1.0/24`, and configure an IP address for the 2nd NIC on each host) 1st, and when doing the Storage XenMotion, when asked which Storage Network to use (step 4 - live migration network), choose the storage network and it should work.